# how to get transaction id from CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile paypal api

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to create recurring payment with paypal. For that i am using this function,

```
function CallShortcutExpressCheckout( $paymentAmount, $currencyCodeType, $paymentType, $returnURL, $cancelURL) 
{
    $nvpstr="&AMT=". $paymentAmount;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&PAYMENTACTION=" . $paymentType;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION=".urlencode($_SESSION['cart']['total_amount']['name']);
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&BILLINGTYPE=RecurringPayments";
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&RETURNURL=" . $returnURL;

    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&INVNUM=" . $_SESSION['cart']['inv'];

    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CANCELURL=" . $cancelURL;
    $nvpstr = $nvpstr . "&CURRENCYCODE=" . $currencyCodeType;

    $_SESSION["currencyCodeType"] = $currencyCodeType;    
    $_SESSION["PaymentType"] = $paymentType;

    $resArray=hash_call("SetExpressCheckout", $nvpstr);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    if($ack=="SUCCESS" || $ack=="SUCCESSWITHWARNING")
    {
        $token = urldecode($resArray["TOKEN"]);
        $_SESSION['TOKEN']=$token;
    }

    return $resArray;
}
```

Which returns the token, then i am creating recurring profile using this function

```
function CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile()
{
    $token      = urlencode($_SESSION['TOKEN']);
    $email      = urlencode($_SESSION['email']);
    $shipToName     = urlencode($_SESSION['shipToName']);
    $shipToStreet       = urlencode($_SESSION['shipToStreet']);
    $shipToCity     = urlencode($_SESSION['shipToCity']);
    $shipToState        = urlencode($_SESSION['shipToState']);
    $shipToZip      = urlencode($_SESSION['shipToZip']);
    $shipToCountry  = urlencode($_SESSION['shipToCountry']);

    $nvpstr="&TOKEN=".$token;
    #$nvpstr.="&EMAIL=".$email;
    $nvpstr.="&SHIPTONAME=".$shipToName;
    $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOSTREET=".$shipToStreet;
    $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOCITY=".$shipToCity;
    $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOSTATE=".$shipToState;
    $nvpstr.= "&DESC=".$_SESSION['cart']['total_amount']['name'];
    $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOZIP=".$shipToZip;
    $nvpstr.="&SHIPTOCOUNTRY=".$shipToCountry;
    /*$nvpstr.="&PROFILESTARTDATE=".urlencode("2015-12-01T0:0:0");*/
    $nvpstr .= "&PROFILESTARTDATE=".date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m", time()), date("d", time()), date("Y", time())))."T00:00:00Z";
    $nvpstr.="&BILLINGPERIOD=Year";
    $nvpstr.="&BILLINGFREQUENCY=1";
    $nvpstr.="&AMT=".$_SESSION['cart']['total_amount']['total'];
    $nvpstr.="&CURRENCYCODE=USD";
    $nvpstr.="&IPADDRESS=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $resArray=hash_call("CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile",$nvpstr);
    $ack = strtoupper($resArray["ACK"]);
    return $resArray;
}
```

But it returns me to `profile-id` not `transaction-id`. I read somewhere that we have to use `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` to complete the payment. But then amount deduct from paypal 2 times.

1)after doing `DoExpressCheckoutPayment`
2)after create `recurring profile`

I am doing anything wrong for recurring payment?
I just thinking, first i need to do `expresscheckout` then i need to create recurring profile and set startdate to next year. so first amount will deduct by `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` then from next year deduct by `recurring profile`.

Is there any better way to play with recurring payment using express checkout? Too much confusion to play with `recurring payment` in paypal.

Please help me to solve this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you call  CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API with token value, there is no transaction id return.
Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/ (CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile Response Message part )
TRANSACTIONID The transaction ID from the direct credit card initial payment.(it doesn't apply to Pay with PayPal method)

CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile API will not deduct money from buyer if you don't set INITAMT parameter in API request. 
In your example.
2)after create recurring profile, no money deducted from buyer.
1)after doing DoExpressCheckoutPayment , money will be deducted from buyer.

In general, it only deduct money once.

Comment: is it that we need to add INITAMT param in the api request to get the `transaction id` in the response ?

Answer (score 0):

We call CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile (without the INITAMT value) to create a subscription. Then we wait for the first recurring_payment IPN notification which should arrive soon afterwards. This is a notification of the first payment and it contains a transaction id (txn_id).